# 2d unity level generator instantiating wrong position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been trying to make my own level generator, which generates a prefab with the correct sprite based on the color that is match in the small map that I made.

More specifically, I made this small map.

[image]

If one of the colors matches one of the colors that are found in a color array, it will instantiate a prefab with the correct sprite and so on for the other colors. So far it instantiates the objects with the correct sprites.

However this is what it looks like when I play the game.

[image]

And this is what it's suppose to look like

[image]

I don't know why it is doing this because based on my code,

```
public Texture2D needColors;
public Texture2D tiles;
public Texture2D level;
public GameObject tile;
public Transform parent;
public Color32[] colors;
public Sprite[] sprites;

void Start(){
    for(int x = 0; x < level.width; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < level.height; y++){
            GenerateLevel(x, y);
        }
    }
}

void GenerateLevel(int x, int y){
    Color32 pixelColor = level.GetPixel(x, y);
    if(pixelColor.a == 0){
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++){
        if(pixelColor.Equals(colors[i])){
            Vector2 position = new Vector2(x, y);
            Instantiate(tile, position, Quaternion.identity, parent);
            tile.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[i];
        }
    }
}
```

it should be skipping the transparent pixels.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: taking a shot in the dark here as I don't fully understand your code - but does it do anything differently if you assign the instantiated object to a new gameobject instead?  
`tilycopy = Instantiate(tile, position, Quaternion.identity, parent) as GameObject;  
 tilecopy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[i];`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I actually didn't post my whole code since I believe the other stuff is not part of the problem. Also, I did tried to make a whole new object based on the prefab, but it produces the same result. I feel like it has to do with the transparent pixels because when it is not transparent it creates the result I want. However I need this pixels to be transparent.

Comment: No worries! Seems to me like the problem is here as well, I just can't figure it out! Though it does appear that most all the tiles are being created properly, but for some reason random sections on the bottom are being shifted up towards the top.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem I am encountering